# Is there anyway to limit bundle version while updating?

Tags: osgi

When I use `update` command in OSGi, the framework (Equinox) uses the file in update location in order to update the bundle. No matter if the bundle in the location has a higher version or not. for example the framework updated version 1.2.0 with 1.0.0.

is there anyway to limit the version of the file that is going to be used as the updated file? I mean something like what we can do in import bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the framework won't do this kind of checking for you. If you don't want to update the bundle from that location, just don't call `update`.

Note that it is possible to update a bundle from a different location than it was originally installed from, using the version of the `update` method that takes an `InputStream`, e.g.:

```
File newLocation = new File("...");
bundle.update(new FileInputStream(newLocation));
```

Comment: So what should I do in order to have this kind of checking?
Am I supposed to develop my own shell or something like that?
My main purpose is to lessen the data transfer.

Comment: You should not have to develop your own shell. Most of the OSGi shells (including the Equinox one) are extensible with new commands, so you could just develop your own "updateIfLater" command.

Comment: How can I obtain bundle's version before installing it? is there any way?

Comment: Read the manifest inside the JAR using `java.util.jar.JarFile`.